# How to create dict from class without None fields?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, dictionary

I have the following dataclass:

```
@dataclass
class Image:
    content_type: str
    data: bytes = b''
    id: str = ""
    upload_date: datetime = None
    size: int = 0

    def to_dict(self) -> Dict[str, Any]:
        result = {}
        if self.id:
            result['id'] = self.id
        if self.content_type:
            result['content_type'] = self.content_type
        if self.size:
            result['size'] = self.size
        if self.upload_date:
            result['upload_date'] = self.upload_date.isoformat()
        return result
```

Is there any way to simplify `to_dict` method? I don't want to list all of the fields using `if`.

Comment: [`asdict()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.asdict)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As suggested by [meowgoesthedog](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8204776), you can use [`asdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.asdict) and filter the result to skip falsy values:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict
from datetime import datetime
from typing import Dict, Any

@dataclass
class Image:
    content_type: str
    data: bytes = b''
    id: str = ""
    upload_date: datetime = None
    size: int = 0

    def to_dict(self) -> Dict[str, Any]:
        return {k: v for k, v in asdict(self).items() if v}

print(Image('a', b'b', 'c', None, 0).to_dict())
# {'content_type': 'a', 'data': b'b', 'id': 'c'}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the `dict` representation of a class object in python by using the  [`vars`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars) method.

First, you need to implement `__setattr__` inside the class. Add this method inside your class.

```py
def __setattr__(self, name, value):
    if value is not None:
        self.__dict__[name] = value
    if value is not None and name == 'upload_date':
        self.__dict__[name] = value.isoformat()
```

This will prevent the `None` fields from being added into the class dict.

```py
>>> img = Image(content_type='something')
>>> vars(i)
{'content_type': 'something', 'data': b'', 'id': '', 'size': 0}
```

However, using `dataclasses.asdict` will still keep the `None` fields.

```py
>>> import dataclasses
>>> img = Image(content_type='something')
>>> dataclasses.asdict(img)
{'content_type': 'something', 'data': b'', 'id': '', 'upload_date': None, 'size': 0}
```

But you can use `vars` since that works. `object.__dict__` returns the same thing as `vars(object)`.

Comment: Works for this simple case but not a good idea if you have e.g. nested dataclasses.

Comment: Thanks, I don't want to store `None` fields in the dict. Please look at `to_dict` implementation

Comment: I've updated my answer. Please check if this works. @petrush