# Dynamic Python Dataclass

Tags: python-3.x, inner-classes, python-dataclasses

I need to minimize the response footprint of an API.  One way we are doing that is eliminating attributes that are null.  Which introduces the challenge to create a dataclass that I can build dynamically.

I have managed to get the dynamic class created and it contains the data I need (viewing in log).  But, I have not been able to get it inserted into the Parent Class.  ParentClass portion is Emtpy with this logic.

```
@dataclass
class VR: pass

@dataclass
class ResultParent:
    validationResult: VR
    matchCandidate: List[matchCandidates] = field(default_factory=list)

  #create and pop dynamic class
  vr = VR()
  if valres.matchStatusCode is not None:
       vr.matchStatusCode = valres.matchStatusCode
  if valres.matchStatusReason is not None:
       vr.matchStatusReason = valres.matchStatusReason
  ...

  #This pprint works and the attr/values are what we want
  pprint(vars(vr))  
 
  #Create ParentClass
  obj = ResultParent([vr],[])

  # The result of the above command is empty

  #Code then continues on to populate matchCandidates and then the ParentClass - no issues there
```

Answer (score -1):

I was able to accomplish this.  I added a setattr that only added the attr if it was not NONE.  Found it in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57305749/how-to-create-dict-from-class-without-none-fields).  Which was the desired result.

```
@dataclass
class VR: 
    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if value is not None:
            self.__dict__[name] = value

@dataclass
class ResultParent:
    validationResult: VR
    matchCandidate: List[matchCandidates] = field(default_factory=list)


vr = VR()
vr.matchStatusCode = p.get('ValAddrStatus')
vr.matchStatusReason = p.get('ValAddrStatusCode')
...

obj = ResultParent([vars(vr)],[])
```